# Tabindex for input type file in IE

Tags: html

When you render:
`<input type="file" />`

you get a box and a button, right? (At least in Firefox and IE.)

in IE how you can tab to (focus) both the box and the button or only button.

Comment: Just for the record, focusing the textbox is/will become obsolete.  For security reasons you can't type in a path/file any more and must interact with the popup file dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The text box and button act as the one element in the browsers so you can only set the tab index to the thing as a whole, not each element. To focus the file input use: $('input[type=file]').focus();

Comment: I had hard time understending the question, too. But I think I finally got it- is there a key combination to switch (tab to) the file input like in firefox? In firefox you only need to press the tab key to get to the next input.

Answer (score 0):

> You get a box and a button, right?

Nope. Google Chrome on Ubuntu, for example, doesn't have a textbox. You shouldn't expect every browser on every OS to have the same ugly form widgets as IE.